# Convert datetime.timedelta Object to HH:MM

Tags: python, mysql

My database table has a column whose datatype is `datetime`, so when queried it returns `HH:MM:SS`. However, using Python it returns `(datetime.timedelta(0, 57360),)`.

This is obviously the time difference in seconds. How do I convert the returned object into a string in the format `HH:MM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how you can print the time:

```py
import datetime

delta = datetime.timedelta(0, 57360)
sec = delta.seconds
hours = sec // 3600
minutes = (sec // 60) - (hours * 60)
print(hours, ':', minutes)
```

you can also print the time with seconds by

```py
print(str(delta))
```

Comment: @Astrodude11 That will work for every delta variable. The specific `delta` value comes as an example.

Comment: @Astrodude11 `foo[0]` is `foo.days`. this is integer. call `foo.seconds` (same as `foo[1]`).

Answer (score 3):

What about this solution:

```
import datetime

td = datetime.timedelta(0, 57360)
print ':'.join(str(td).split(':')[:2])
```